# Date time picker adds 00:00:00 in timestamp, i want current time instead of Wed May 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Tags: angular, datetime, datetimepicker, owl-date-time

I'm getting a date as **Wed May 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**, instead of 
Wed May 27 2020 12:34:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time).

I'm using angular ng date time picker, it works fine everywhere but just return 00:00:00 in once component.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="From" [owlDateTime]="dt4" class="custom" name="fromTime" [(ngModel)]="fromTime"
(ngModelChange)="validatetime()"></span>
<span class="example-trigger" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt4">
<i class="fas fa-calendar-alt blue hand"></i>
</span>
<owl-date-time [pickerType]="'calendar'" #dt4></owl-date-time>
```

```
fromTime: any;
```

Comment: Have your excluded time intentionally from the `owl-date-time` and just want to show in the method and not the calendar?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't specified `[pickerType]="'calendar'"` intentionally please remove it and it will start displaying time alongside of the date

```html
<owl-date-time #dt4></owl-date-time>
```